# Срабатывание функции JS при загрузке страницы, но с обязательным условием. Подскажите как сделать?

Tags: javascript, select, выборка

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы скрипт выполнялся при загрузке страницы (либо после полной загрузки страницы), но при этом использовал обязательно условие.
Есть событие `onchange="MYFUNCT2(this);"`, которое срабатывает при выборе любого пункта из списка select по id, кроме пункта id=0. Не важно, пункт с id=0 находится в начале/в середине/в конце списка. Если вручную выборку делаешь, то все замечательно работает.
При загрузке страницы, выбранный пункт может находиться на любой строке (на любом ID), так как он динамически подгружается из базы. Как мне сделат так, чтобы при загрузке страницы, скрипт "видел", что в поле select выбран любой пункт, кроме id=0 и соответственно отрабатывал функцию MYFUNCT2(this). А в случае, если id=0, то функция MYFUNCT2(this) не отрабатывалась бы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по

> срабатывает при выборе любого пункта из списка select по id, кроме
>   пункта id=0

проверка выбранного элемента в селекте - встроена в функцию `MYFUNCT2`.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var s = document.getElementById("mySelect");
  MYFUNCT2(s);
};

function MYFUNCT2(select) { 
  var o = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
  if (o.id == "0")
    console.log(o.id, "Zero selected - do nothing.");
  else
    console.log(o.id, "Not zero selected - do something.");
}
```

```html
<select id="mySelect" onchange="MYFUNCT2(this)">
  <option id="1">One</option>
  <option id="2" selected>Two</option>
  <option id="0">Zero</option>
  <option id="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое) Все сработало, как было задумано)

Comment: @toxi На здоровье. Успехов!